# Mastercard Payment Gateway Services on magento 1.9.3.9

Tags: magento, payment, mastercard

I installed magento extension 'Mastercard Payment Gateway Services' but it didn't work on magento 1.9.3.9, when i'm trying to open System >> configuration >> Payments Method (HTTP ERROR 500); 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mastercard_Mpgs_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Fieldset_Hint' not found in /home/.../public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 28913.
Need help

Comment: Is this an upgrade, or your first attempt to install `magneto`? The 500 error suggests that you are making a connection. Is the error message you get referring to a local file? If so, can you include it?

Comment: Hello I founded the solution:
1. Remove the extension (MPGS) from the Magento. 
2. Disable the compilation (System > Tools > Compilation). 
3. Clear the cache 
4. Install the extension now. 
5. Enable the compilation 
6. Run Compilation Process 
7. Clear the cache.